# Hangman Project While Loop Trouble

Tags: python

I'm working on a hangman project for class during this corona virus spring break and it wont work. The while loop in Game() isn't working. It runs perfect until the end, then it wont exit the while loop and run win(). It stays in the while loop and say's "Make a guess . . . " and refuses to exit no matter what i've tried. Can anyone help figure this out?

```
from datetime import time
from time import sleep
import sys
import random

Hangman1 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |       
      |    
      |   
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman2 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |    |    
      | 
      |    
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman3 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |    |     
      |    |
      |   
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman4 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |   /|     
      |    |
      |    
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman5 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |   /|\     
      |    |
      |    
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman6 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |   /|\     
      |    |
      |   ]  
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""
Hangman7 = """
       ____
      |    |      
      |    0      
      |   /|\     
      |    |
      |   ] ] 
     _|_
    |   |______
    |          |
    |__________|"""


alPH = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
        "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

wordList = ["love and bacon","i eat bananas","potato","odyssey","cats and dogs","heartlands","dingo","omega","mr coffee","family", "mississippi"]


w = random.choice(wordList)
w = w.lower()
blankLst = []
wrongLst = []



def Intro():

    animation = "|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|"
    print("Loading . . . ")
    for i in range(81):
        sleep(.1)
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)])
        sys.stdout.flush()
    if (animation == "|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|\-/|"):
        print()
        print()
        Game()

def Game():
    for i in w:
        if (i != " "):
            blankLst.append("_")
        else:
            blankLst.append(" ")
    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    print()
    sleep(1)
    print("Lets Begin!!")
    print()
    sleep(1)
    print(" ".join(blankLst))
    print()
    sleep(1.5)
    tries = 7
    while tries != 0:
        guess = input("Make a Guess   ")
        print()
        guess = guess.lower()

        if guess in w:
            for i in range(len(w)):
                if (w[i] == guess):
                    blankLst[i] = w[i]
            print(" ".join(blankLst))
            sleep(1)
            print("Good Job!!!")

        elif guess not in w:
            sleep(1)
            print("Sorry not a letter, you have " +str(tries - 1)+ " tries left. Try again. . . ")
            tries -= 1
            if (tries == 6):
              print(Hangman1)
            elif (tries == 5):
              print(Hangman2)
            elif (tries == 4):
              print(Hangman3)
            elif (tries == 3):
              print(Hangman4)
            elif (tries == 2):
              print(Hangman5)
            elif (tries == 1):
              print(Hangman6)
            elif (tries == 0):
              print(Hangman7)
              sleep(1)
              lose()
    win()




def lose():
    print("You lose. . .")
    sleep(1)
    play = (input("Would you like you play again?    ")).lower()
    if (play == "y"):
        sleep(.75)
        Intro()
    elif(play == "n"):
        print("Dont forget to come back some time.")
def win():
    print("You Win!!")
    sleep(1)
    play = (input("Would you like you play again?    ")).lower()
    if (play == "y"):
        sleep(.75)
        Intro()
    elif(play == "n"):
        print("Dont forget to come back some time.")


def onStart():
    print("-~-~-~HANGMAN~-~-~-")
    print()
    sleep(1.5)
    play = (input("""       Start
     ( y / n )
         """)).lower()
    if (play == "y"):
        sleep(.75)
        Intro()
    elif(play == "n"):
        print("Dont forget to come back some time.")
onStart()
```

Comment: 1) break out of the while loop if you win (after `print("Good Job!!!")`). 2) avoid what are in fact recursive calls. You need a main program to call the various parts instead

Comment: How do I do that? Well I can see that I need to get rid of my while statement, but then it runs it and stops at the end of the if and or elif statement.

Comment: If you guess right, you never increment `tries`, and so your `while` loop never ends because that's the criterion. You need a second condition in your loop for counting successful letters and then using `break`

Comment: Would I need to do that with an ```if():``` statement or, cause I tried using ```if():``` after and before the ```while :``` and after ```print("Good Job!!!")```.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `break` after `print("Good Job!!!")`. You  don't need any additional statements.